# Using PayPal REST api in Node.js

Tags: node.js, paypal

After reading their docs and [github API page](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) I understand that in order to complete a transaction I need

i) Create the payment using the `paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) { .. });` function from their API and to provide a payment object. Get the redirect url and in some way provide it to the user in order to pay.

ii) Execute the payment `paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) { .. });` (thats where my issue is, more on that later)

iii) And lastly, authorize the payment.

I understand the first part and I have no issue either with the PayPal response or using it. My issue is the second function. Since I'd like to send the URL to the user and I don't have a button there, I cant understand how to wait for the execute response. Suppose I send the URL to the user and the user pays, how can I wait for the response to run the execute function afterward.

Should I create a server (with no actual website) listening to a random port?

Comment: Try sending the redirect URL back to the client side and initiate a client-side redirect using that URL and upon successful payment, handle the success route in Node.js and send back the required details back to the user. Hope it helps.

Comment: My whole issue is how to handle the success route without website.